# Resizing GIF Animated Image using Java

Tags: java, gif

I am using Java to resize an Animated GIF image. But I have some problems like the animation is not working as expected in the resized image and secondly the quality of the image created is very bad. Please any one let me know if we have any existing libraries or ideas to solve this problem.
Thanks
N.G

Comment: You cannot magically create quality (image content)

Comment: Resizing gifs will always produce bad quality - 8bit images do not resize well. Resizing multiple frames of an 8bit image, independently of each other, will also produce horrible color artifacts. You should try getting the original (higher quality?) source of the image and produce a NEW gif instead.

Comment: getting bad quality would be achieved if we resize it to bigger size, isn't? Then, how about resizing 'em into smaller size... wouldn't be unnoticed...? :D

Comment: Hi Guys, I figured out the solution, if any one is having the same problem you are welcome to contact me

Comment: @NaiveGeek What is the solutions anyway? :D

Comment: How would we contact you through this site? Please just post your answer...